# Intersection and conditioned set

Tags: probability, statistics, elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

I don't understand why if it's true that $P(A\cap B|C)=P(A|C)\cdot P(B|C)$ (formula, moreover, used in a number of exercises), in this case he writes:
[image]

Comment: Actually, I do not believe that $P(A\cap B|C)=P(A|C)\cdot P(B|C)$ was used in the calculation. It seems more to be something like $P(A\cap B|C)=P(A|B)\cdot P(B|C)$. This is not true in general, there has to be some assumption on $A,B,C$. What is true however is that $P(A\cap B|C)=P(A|B \cap C)\cdot P(B|C)$.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch Thanks for your answer. Well, you're welcome to watch the solution that i post below.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch I'm sorry for my reponse comment, i don't speak english so well. In any case, the photo up here is referring to the following exercise. You have 5 coins and $p_i$ is the probability that the $i$ coin gives Head (T), where $p_1=0,p_2=0,25,p_3=0,5,p_4=0,75,p_5=1$. One coin is extrracted and launched. You obtain Head (T). If the same $i$ coin launched again, what is the probability to obtain another Head (T)?

Answer (score 0):

Example like the following: [image: this]

Thanks again.